# How to use groupby to make unique User ID level dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input dataframe as ID Visit11 Visit12 Visit13 Visit14 Visit15

```
1   Orange              
2   Orange              
2       Apple           
3   Grapes              
4   Apple               
5   Not Defined             
5       Apple           
6   Apple               
7   Banana              
7                   
7                   
7                   
7                   
7                   
7                   
8   Banana              
8       Apple           
8           Banana      
8               Apple   
8                   Banana
9                   
9                   
9                   
9
```

---

I am using groupby to get the expected output but it's clubbing all the purchase into 1 cell. I want the purchase to be clubbed in different columns where 1 row is for 1 user. The expected output should be

---

```
    ID  Visit11 Visit12 Visit13 Visit1Int4  Visit15
1   Orange              
2   Orange  Apple           
3   Grapes              
4   Apple               
5   Not Defined Apple           
6   Apple               
7   Banana              
8   Banana  Apple   Banana  Apple   Banana
9
```

Comment: Why does your data look like this?

Comment: I'm not able to edit here properly. These are the columns "ID Visit11 Visit12 Visit13 Visit14 Visit15"

Comment: Can you do something like `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` and paste the output in your question? I'll fix it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
print (df)
   ID      Visit11 Visit12
0   1       Orange        
1   2               Orange
2   2        Apple        
3   3       Grapes        
4   4        Apple        
5   5  Not Defined        
6   5                Apple

df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df1 = df.set_index('ID').stack().unstack().sort_index(axis=1).reset_index().fillna('')
print (df1)
   ID      Visit11 Visit12
0   1       Orange        
1   2        Apple  Orange
2   3       Grapes        
3   4        Apple        
4   5  Not Defined   Apple
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df1 = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).first().fillna('')
print (df1)
   ID      Visit11 Visit12
0   1       Orange        
1   2        Apple  Orange
2   3       Grapes        
3   4        Apple        
4   5  Not Defined   Apple
```

Comment: The first solution gave me an error "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". However, the alternate one worked. Thanks

Comment: @shreeja7 - OK, super, only test if some data are not lost, because `groupby.first` get only first value per groups per column.